# Fresh QGIS 3.12 and 3.10 Installation result in unknown error when saving Spatialite layer

Tags: qgis, spatialite, windows-10

This is the most interesting problem to resolve.
On a brand new Windows 10 HP Laptop, I install Windows with the latest updates and then install both versions of QGIS 3.10 and 3.12.
On creating a new Spatalite layer, I add a few Point type and click Save.
The system returns with Unknown cause:

```
SQLite errors: unknown cause
SQL: INSERT INTI "test"("geometry",)VALUES (GeomFromWKB(?4326),)
```

I imported a GeoJSON file with the Point geometry and this worked as expected.
The final test is to create a row using the DB Browser for Spatialite.  This returned "error adding record no such function GeometryConstraints" which is unexpected.

Any guidance to understand what is wrong on a PC that has no other software?

Thanks

Comment: QGIS 3.12 and 3.10.3 have some issues with Spatialite. There are issues logged on GitHub and hopefully they will be fixed with the next update which is due on the 20th of this month.